# Django: 404 on every request

Tags: python, django, http

I have a Django 1.6.5 application that runs on my development environment. But when deploying to the production server it gives me this error on every request:

> WARNING 2014-06-20 14:35:40,085 base Not Found: /
>
> Not Found: /
>
> [20/Jun/2014 14:35:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1600

And it happens the same with every mapped url that works on development:

> WARNING 2014-06-20 14:39:59,151 base Not Found: /vars
>
> Not Found: /vars
>
> [20/Jun/2014 14:39:59] "GET /vars HTTP/1.1" 404 1608

My urls.py looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^facebook/', include('django_facebook.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('django_facebook.auth_urls')),
    url(r'^vars/', VarsView.as_view(), name='vars'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^main/', MainView.as_view(), name='main'),
    url(r'^logout/', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    url(r'^about/', AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
)
```

I will appreciate any help with this. I'm stucked here for days.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have a different settings.py for development compared to production?

Comment: @MatthewFranglen Yes. I'm running on the same git branch. Both are synchronized.

Comment: I would recommend reviewing the differences. I have found that the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting can interfere with production deployments. Just a guess :)

Comment: Stupid question, is the production server using the same stack as your development server?

Comment: @MatthewFranglen ALLOWED_HOSTS would be a clue but I'm still running in DEBUG=True and doing the tests using wget localhost:8000 from the server.

Comment: @wdh hhmmm not exactly, but all required libraries are the same in both environments. I will double check using pip.

Comment: I think @wdh meant to ask if you are using the same full application stack, e.g. apache+mod_wsgi+python3.4+django1.6.5, or nginx+uwsgi+python2.7+django1.6.5

Comment: Ah no. In prod I have a apache+mod_wsgi. But to overcome this issue im just running from command line [python manage.py runserver] inside git test branch, and doing wget's to localhost.

Comment: is the server log outputting anything when the request 404's?

Comment: Oui:
wget localhost:8000
in django log:
WARNING 2014-06-20 15:48:44,040 base Not Found: /
Not Found: /
[20/Jun/2014 15:48:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1600

Comment: only thing i can think of is if you accidentally have something in your .gitignore that you shouldnt, because it sounds like your root URL config doesnt exist, or isnt set right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55995/discussion-between-pseudonym117-and-akim).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel so dumb now.

The problem was that I had a get_list_or_404 in the index view. And any other request was redirected to index.

Strange thing is that I have DEBUG = True on my settings file, and wasn't able to see full error log in the html, just a simple 404 instead.

Thanks and regards.